# Using expand.grid function with n elements

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I need to generate all the combinations of `1:n` repeated `n` times. Example with `n = 4`:

```
expand.grid(1:4, 1:4, 1:4, 1:4)
```

This method, however, will require a lot of typing when `n` is a larger number. Is there an efficient way to do this? I Tried `paste` and couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 4):

We can `rep`licate into a `list` and apply the `expand.grid`

```
n <- 4
expand.grid(rep(list(seq_len(n)), n))
```

---

Or use `replicate`

```
expand.grid(replicate(n, seq_len(n), simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: I see what you did there!! I may have to `rep`eat this usage.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you are looking for permutations with repetition, not combinations. Secondly, there are several packages for obtaining this efficiently in `R`. There is the classical package `gtools` and there are the two highly efficient compiled libraries `arrangements` and `RcppAlgos` (I am the author):

```
## library(gtools)
gtools::permutations(4, 4, repeats.allowed = TRUE)

## library(arrangements)
arrangements::permutations(4, 4, replace = TRUE)

## library(RcppAlgos)
RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(4, 4, TRUE)
```